# c++ read IE history from service running as system

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com, impersonation

I have a service running as system written in c++ 
The service should read IE history (versions 7-11) of the current logged on user.
I use impersonation in order to run under the user privileges 
When I run this code from user context (without impersonation) the code prints the IE history, but running from system it returns nothing. 
Any idea what is wrong?

```
//Some impersonation code    
CoInitialize(NULL);

STATURL url;
wstring strUrl;
ULONG uFetched;
IUrlHistoryStg2Ptr history;
IEnumSTATURLPtr enumPtr;

if (FAILED(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUrlHistory,
    NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_IUrlHistoryStg2,
    (void**)&history)))
{
    cout << "ERROR CoCreateInstance";
    return false;
}

if (FAILED(history->EnumUrls(&enumPtr))) {
    cout << "ERROR EnumUrls";
    return false;
}

while (SUCCEEDED(enumPtr->Next(1, &url, &uFetched)))
{
    if (uFetched == 0)
        break;
    strUrl = url.pwcsUrl;
    wcout << strUrl << endl;
}

CoUninitialize();
```